# Can I sell an unscheduled compound as a recreational drug in the USA?

Tags: is-x-legal, drugs, fda

From the [Oxilofrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxilofrine) Wikipedia page:

> Legal Status US: Unapproved "New Drug" (as defined by 21 U.S. Code § 321(p)(1)). Use in dietary supplements, food, or medicine is unlawful; otherwise uncontrolled.

Does this mean I can sell oxilofrine as something other than a dietary supplement, food, or medicine? I could not figure this out from basic research on Google.

Comment: what other category do you want to class it in that is not food, dietary supplement or medicine and offered by the FDA?

Answer (score 2):

If you are offering it as a recreational drug, then it requires FDA approval.

If you do sell it, though, you face criminal charges for selling a drug not approved by the FDA which is, generally speaking, much less serious a crime than selling a controlled substance like cocaine or meth.

Comment: What if I sell it not as a recreational drug but simply as a chemical?